# Type() cannot confirm view SWIFTUI

Tags: swiftui

```
@ObservedObject var taskModel = TaskViewModel()

var body: some View {
   
    
    ScrollView(.vertical , showsIndicators:false){

        VStack{

            CustomSegmentedBar()
            if taskModel.currentTab == "Done"{
                
                taskModel.getTasks()
            
            }else if taskModel.currentTab == "Today"{
                
                TaskView()
            }
        }.padding()
        
    }
```

i am trying to filter my task object depending on the segmented control and then display it in a list but xcode is giving me a error > Type() cannot confirm view. I am really confused

Comment: I assume the `taskModel.getTasks()` is not a view, but should be a view there. Do filtering in model view.

Comment: @Asperi i am trying but it wont update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could try something like this:

```
@StateObject var taskModel = TaskViewModel()

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical , showsIndicators:false){
        VStack {
            CustomSegmentedBar()
            if taskModel.currentTab == "Today" {
                TaskView()
            }
        }.padding()
        .onAppear {
            if taskModel.currentTab == "Done" {
                taskModel.getTasks()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this did not work sir, the current tab is only changing in the view

Comment: what exactly is not working? I don't understand what you mean by `the current tab is only changing in the view`. Can you show more code on what you are doing and how you use your `taskModel` in the (other) Views.